# Trying to use millis instead of delay for a switch state loop

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to write a code for an Arduino, which is a model of a redlight.
The idea is that pressing the button will switch to the first state (turning LEDs on and off).
Then the second and finally the third state will revert it back to the first state waiting for the button to be pressed again

There is the need for a time gap between the 2 states....it works perfectly well using the delay() function

But I am not allowed to use it, so instead, I am trying to use millis(), the idea is that the time should start once the button is pressed and stop once it's reverts back to the first state and restart over once the button is pressed again.
And it's sadly not working, whenever I press the button nothing happens.

Does anybody know how I can fix it?
here is the code:

```
const long delay2 = 4000;

int but = 2;
int leda = 3;
int ledb = 4;
int ledc = 5;
int ledd = 6;
int lede = 7;
volatile byte state=LOW;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    for(int p=3; p <= 8; p++) pinMode(p, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(but, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(but), changestate, FALLING);
}

void car(){
    digitalWrite(leda, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledb, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledc, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledd, LOW);
    digitalWrite(lede, HIGH);
}
void wait(){
    digitalWrite(leda, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledb, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledc, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledd, LOW);
    digitalWrite(lede, HIGH);
}
void ped(){
    digitalWrite(leda, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledb, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledc, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledd, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(lede, LOW);
}
void changestate() {
    state=state+1; 
    if (state > 3){
        state=0; 
    }
}

void loop(){
    switch(state){
        case 0:
            car();
            unsigned long start_time = millis();
            break;
        case 1:
            wait();
            while (millis() > start_time + delay1);  
              state=2;
            break;
        case 2:
           ped();
           while (millis() > start_time + delay2);
            state=0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} 


EDIT: The issue has been solved! Here's the code for further reference: 

#define delay1 500
#define delay2 4000


int but = 2;
int leda = 3;
int ledb = 4;
int ledc = 5;
int ledd = 6;
int lede = 7;
volatile byte state=LOW;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    for(int p=3; p <= 8; p++) pinMode(p, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(but, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(but), changestate, FALLING);
}

void car(){
    digitalWrite(leda, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledb, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledc, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledd, LOW);
    digitalWrite(lede, HIGH);
}
void wait(){
    digitalWrite(leda, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledb, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledc, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledd, LOW);
    digitalWrite(lede, HIGH);
}
void ped(){
    digitalWrite(leda, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledb, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledc, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledd, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(lede, LOW);
}
void changestate() {
    state=state+1; 
    if (state > 3){
        state=0; 
    }
}

unsigned long start_time = millis();
void loop(){
    switch(state){
        case 0:
            car();
            break;
        case 1:
            start_time = millis();
            while(millis() < start_time + delay1){
              wait();
              state=2;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
           while(millis() < start_time + delay2){
             ped();
           }
            state=0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pick one tag, C or C++.

Comment: My apologies, I am kinda new to stack overflow.

Comment: @user17732522 I saw serial.begin but that could very well have been a function pointer in a struct. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: I'm always amazed at what people can do with C's preprocessor macros to make it loko like a different language.

Comment: Your state will change irrespective of if the necessary time has elapsed or not because the state change is connected to an interrupt.  This `p <= 8;` should probably be `p < 8;` because your highest pin is 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an untested suggestion.  It only allows state changes if a sufficient amount of time has passed.  You may want to have different times in an array `if (millis() - start_time > mydelays[state]) {`

```
volatile bool change_allowed = true;
volatile bool statechanged = true;
volatile unsigned long start_time = 0;

void changestate() {        
    if (millis() - start_time > DELAY) {
        change_allowed = true;
    }
    if (change_allowed) {
        start_time = millis();
        change_allowed = false;
        state=state+1;
        statechanged = true;
        if (state > 2) {
            state=0; 
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    if (statechanged) {
        statechanged = false;
        switch(state){
            case 0:
...
}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, the LEDs flicker very quickly once the button is pressed but it remains in the first state.

Comment: Small change: `if (state > 3) {` should be `if (state > 2) {` because you only have three states, numbered 0, 1 and 2.  Also, it is the `changestate()` function that changes the state, NOT `loop()`, so _remove_ all `state=N` from loop()!

Comment: `loop()` shouldn't do anything if state hasn't actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

Problematic things in code:

- `unsigned long start_time = millis();` `start_time` can't be a local variable. After break command, loop function will end. Local variable on the stack will be destroed. After new calling loop will created again and content is unpredictable. Make it global.
- `while (millis() > start_time + delay1);` if this become true it will hangup for 49 days. You probably want do `while (millis() < start_time + delay1);` But this is same as use `delay()`
- `millis() < start_time + delay1;` don't use this form. It produce falsely result shortly before internal counter overflow (every 49.x days). Use form `(millis() - start_time > delay1` This calculate valid  elapsed time also if result of millis() is lower then `start_time`

Also, do you have debouced button? It's seem as school exercise. I will don't write code for you. Only standart hint - Use `Serial.println()` to log where your code is running and what is in yours variables.